# Header Footer events not working as expected

Tags: java, itext7

I'm trying to generate a PDF using iText7 with header and footer. However the codes does not work as expected. Here is my code.

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.DeviceRgb;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.Event;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.IEventHandler;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.PdfDocumentEvent;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Canvas;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.borders.Border;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.List;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;


class TextHeaderEventHandler implements IEventHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(docEvent.getPage());

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(35, 740, 520, 100);
        pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, rectangle).setFontSize(7);
        // load logo image here and add
        // canvas.add(image);

        canvas.add(new Paragraph("My custom header line goes here."));

        // bottom line
        canvas.add(new Paragraph("---------------------------------------------------------------------"));
    }
}


class TextFooterEventHandler implements IEventHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {

        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(docEvent.getPage());

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(35, 30, 520, 50);
        pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, rectangle).setFontSize(7);
        // bottom line
        canvas.add(new Paragraph("---------------------------------------------------------------------"));

        // footer text
        canvas.add(new Paragraph("My custom footer line goes here."));
    }
}

/**
 * https://turkogluc.com/java-creating-pdf-reports-with-itext/
 */
public class HeaderFooter {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HeaderFooter.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Properties log4jProperties = new Properties();
        log4jProperties.put("log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender", "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender");
        log4jProperties.put("log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout", "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout");
        log4jProperties.put("log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern", "%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n");
        log4jProperties.put("log4j.rootLogger", "DEBUG, ConsoleAppender");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jProperties);

        HeaderFooter main = new HeaderFooter();
        main.generatePdf();
    }

    public void generatePdf() throws IOException {
        // Creating a PdfWriter
        String dest = "/tmp/example.pdf";
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);

        // Creating a PdfDocument
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);

        // Creating a Document
        Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
        document.setFontSize(10);

        pdfDoc.addNewPage(PageSize.A4);
        document.setMargins(80, 36, 80, 36);
        pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, new TextHeaderEventHandler());
        pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new TextFooterEventHandler());

        // Adding a new page
        pdfDoc.addNewPage(PageSize.A4);
        // document.setMargins(80, 36, 60, 36);

        String content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...jjjj";
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(content);
        paragraph.setFontSize(14);
        paragraph.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        paragraph.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
        paragraph.setFirstLineIndent(20);
        paragraph.setItalic();
        paragraph.setBold();
        paragraph.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(245, 245, 245));
        paragraph.setMargin(10);
        paragraph.setPaddingLeft(10);
        paragraph.setPaddingRight(10);
        paragraph.setWidth(1000);
        paragraph.setHeight(100);
        document.add(paragraph);

        int listIndex = 1;
        List list = new List();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++, listIndex++) {
            list.add("Java --> " + listIndex);
            list.add("Go");
            list.add("React");
            list.add("Apache Kafka");
            list.add("Jenkins");
            list.add("Elastic Search");
        }
        document.add(list);

        // adding a table adds a rectangle into the header part
        Table table = new Table(new float[]{150F, 150F, 150F, 150F});
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Id")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Name")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Location")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Date")));

        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("1000")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Item-1")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Istanbul")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("01/12/2020")));

        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("1005")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Item-2")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Warsaw")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("05/12/2020")));
        document.add(table);

        // extra list
        list = new List();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++, listIndex++) {
            list.add("Java --> " + listIndex);
            list.add("Go");
            list.add("React");
            list.add("Apache Kafka");
            list.add("Jenkins");
            list.add("Elastic Search");
        }
        document.add(list);

        // Closing the document
        document.close();
    }
}
```

**I see following issues.**

- Header is not generated for first page but footer is generated.

[image: PAGE HEADER FOR PAGE 1]

- When I have a table, a rectangle is added to the header randomly on any
  page.

[image: Rectangle with table]

- When I remove table the rectangle goes away. But this way will be able to add table in
  the pdf but I definitely want to add.

[image: No rectangle when table is removed]

Am I missing something? Can anybody help here.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! it would be best if you could narrow down your problem piecemeal and write it in accordance to [mcve]. skimmed your question, its kind of overwhelming given the amount of questions.

Comment: Thanks for the info @BagusTesa, I've 2 questions. 

1. Why is the header not getting added to Page 1 

2. why is a rectangles added to header when I use tables in the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

According to a comment you essentially have two questions:

> Thanks for the info @BagusTesa, I've 2 questions. 1. Why is the header not getting added to Page 1 2. why is a rectangles added to header when I use tables in the pdf.

## 1. Why is the header not getting added to Page 1

You first add the new page and only thereafter register the event listener:

```java
pdfDoc.addNewPage(PageSize.A4);
document.setMargins(80, 36, 80, 36);
pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, new TextHeaderEventHandler());
pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new TextFooterEventHandler());
```

Thus, when the `START_PAGE` event for that first page is triggered, there is no listener yet to draw the header.

If you want that `TextHeaderEventHandler` to also work for the first page, register it *before* creating any pages.

Actually you are adding content only via the `Document` instance which creates the required pages automatically. Why would you call `addNewPage` at all? Best try without that.

## 2. why is a rectangles added to header when I use tables in the pdf.

Well, first of all there is a rectangle because you create a rectangle path:

```java
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(35, 740, 520, 100);
pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle);
```

It usually doesn't show because you don't do anything with that rectangle path you created. You don't fill the path or stroke the path, you merely define it and let it dangle in the air. If later content you add causes the then current path to be stroked, this might make PDF viewers eventually also stroke the dangling path you defined. Probably adding the table includes such a path stroking instruction.

## Applying these findings to your code

Originally your code produces this:

[image: Screenshot original result]

One clearly sees the missing header on page 1 and the rectangle lines around the header on page 2.

Now we remove the two

```
pdfDoc.addNewPage(PageSize.A4);
```

lines. The result:

[image: Screenshot result without addNewPage calls]

One sees that on page 1 something happened in the header area: Where on page 2 there is a stroked rectangle, we here now have a filled rectangle.

Thus, let's deal with the rectangles now and remove the two

```
pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle);
```

lines from the event listener. The result:

[image: screenshot without even the pdfCanvas.rectangle calls]

We see the expected headers on all pages and no weird stroked or filled rectangles.

Comment: Hi @mkl, thanks for the response. However even if I remove pdfDoc.addNewPage(PageSize.A4); call before setting EventHandler, header is not getting added. In fact it does not even honour  the top margin for first page.

Comment: You are adding via the `Document` instance. Why do you call `addNewPage` at all? Please try without that.

Comment: unfortunately, removing all addNewPage call does not work. I still have the same problems.

Comment: @KiranKyle *"unfortunately, removing all addNewPage call does not work. I still have the same problems"* -   Ok, so I copied your code, removed all `addNewPage` calls and all `pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle)` calls (see my answer to your second partial question). The result: headers and footers on all pages, no weird boxes, see the additional section "Applying these findings to your code" in my answer. What problem exactly do you still have?